Как сделать фильтрация продуктов в cms netcat
Всем привет. Есть вот такой блок с тегами


<div class="body-tabs__tags">
    <a href="#" class="body-tabs__tag">Начальные классы</a>
    <a href="#" class="body-tabs__tag">Группа продленного дня</a>
    <a href="#" class="body-tabs__tag">Логопедия</a>
        еще ссылки=>
</div>



и в каждой карточке товара есть


<div class="products-block__tags">
        <a href="#" class="products-block__tag">Развитие речи</a>
        <a href="#" class="products-block__tag">Логопедия</a>
</div> 



блок с тегами к котором относится товар. Нужно сделать фильтрацию, чтобы при нажатии на определенный тег отображались товары у которых этот тег есть. Важно что все это на cms netcat. Не пойму как подключится к базе данных и все правильно сделать на данной платформе.
